# CSS: Can't move my button vertically

Tags: html, css, button, vertical-alignment

I got the following simple HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="bar">
          <span>
               Palavra       
          </span>
      <form>
          <input class="buttom" type="submit" value=""> 
      </form>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS code is like this:

```
#bar{
    width:100%;
    height:7%;
    background-color:#5959AB;
    color:white;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:150%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 190%;
}

.buttom{
background: url(icone_dicionario.jpg) no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
width: 40px;
height: 41px;
}

input{
    position:relative;
    bottom:1000%;
    left:13%;
}



html, body{
height:100%;
}
```

Take a look at the `input` style on the CSS. The element it represents (a button in a dictionary icon) is obeying  the horizontal position ("`left: 13%`") i give it, but not the vertical (don't matter the value I put on it), as you can see:

[image]

can someone help me?

PS: I want the button to appear inside the bar, aside that word...

Comment: It looks like your are after a centered input and centered text. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jkqtfez1/) using `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`

Answer (score 1):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehgtvjr5/)

Just add the attribute **top: -40px;** to the **input** style.
Because the input's width is fixed.

```
input{
    position:relative;
    bottom:1000%;
    left:13%;
    top:-40px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, just didn't understodd why "-top" works and "bottom" doesn't

Comment: @user3708854 If both top and bottom are specified (technically, not auto), top wins.
If both left and right are specified, left wins when direction is ltr  and right wins when direction is rtl .   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to make your div position relative and your button position absolute, then set the top position instead of the bottom. you can use negative numbers for the position as well.

Answer (score 0):

you set **"position:relative;"** for your input. the name "relative" implies that the element's position is relative to itself. if you want to make it vertical, you may choose one of the followings:

1. use top instead of botoom and use pixels (px) instead of percentage (%)
2. use **"position:absolute;"** and use way smaller units or else the element will vanish from the visible part of the screen

if you want the icon to be inside the bar **you must specify a position to the bar class**. something like:

```
 #bar
 {
   position:relative;
  /* rest of css */
 }
```

then you may use the **absolute position** for you **icon**. place in with **top:0px;** and **right:0px;** to make it "stick" to the top-right corner of your bar

Comment: I want the button to appear aside the word and inside the bar, as I just said in the last edition... and that big value is just to show it's not moving anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use 'display: inline-block'?

eg.

```
#bar span {display: inline-block}
form {display: inline-block}
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/483pm2x6/2/